# Updating BufferedImage

Tags: java

So I have this canvas, a BufferedImage, and I have two default calls where I make a line and a circle. My issue here is that I'm trying to call, lets say `drawCircle(...)` in when a user lets say put `1` into the textfield and sumbit it with enter like this:

```java
if (input.equals("1")){
    System.out.println("drawCircle");
    DrawCanvas drawCanvas = new DrawCanvas();
    drawCanvas.drawCircle(330,310,50);
}
```

But when I write 1 in the textfield and submit that, I only get the system output "drawCircle", but the circle is not shown?

I thought that my `reprint()` would update it, but it doesn't, so I'm a bit stuck..

Here is the code I use for making the circle and line and so on:

```java
package DrawCanvas;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    final private BufferedImage canvas;
    final private Color def_c = Color.BLACK; final private Color def_bg = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    public DrawCanvas() {
        int width = 1280; int height = 720;
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        fillCanvas(def_bg);
        int x0 = 0;
        int x1 = 100;
        int y0 = 0;
        int y1 = 100;
        //drawRect(Color.RED, 0, 0, width/2, height/2);
        drawLine(def_c, x0, y0, x1, y1);
        //drawLineRecInit(Color.yellow, x0, y0+2, x1, y1+2);
        drawCircle(300,300,100);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(canvas, null, null);
    }


    public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
        int color = c.getRGB();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // Implementation from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases
    public void drawLine(Color c, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
    {
        int dx = Math.abs(x1-x0);
        int sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        int dy = -Math.abs(y1-y0);
        int sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
        int err = dx + dy;  /* error value e_xy */
        while (true)   /* loop */
        {
            canvas.setRGB(x0, y0, c.getRGB());
            if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) break;
            int e2 = 2*err;
            if (e2 >= dy) /* e_xy+e_x > 0 */
            {
                err += dy;
                x0 += sx;
            }
            if (e2 <= dx) /* e_xy+e_y < 0 */
            {
                err += dx;
                y0 += sy;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }


    public void drawCircle(int x_center, int y_center, int r){
        // inspiration : https://www.gatevidyalay.com/mid-point-circle-drawing-algorithm/
        Color c = def_c;
        int x=r, y=0, p = 1-r;

        // checking for radius of circle
        if(r==0){
            drawPoint(x_center,y_center,c);
        }
        if(r<0)
            return;

        // initialising point p
        while(x>y){
            y++;
            if (p < 0) {
                p = p + 2 * y + 1;
            } else {
                x--;
                p = p+2*y-2*x+1;
            }
            //print all octaves
            drawPoint(x + x_center,y + y_center,c);     // 1. (x,y)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,x + y_center,c);     // 1. (y,x)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);    // 4. (y,-x)
            drawPoint(x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);    // 4. (x,-y)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);   // 3. (-x,-y)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);   // 3. (-y,-x)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,x + y_center,c);    // 2. (-y,x)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,y + y_center,c);    // 2. (-x,y)
        }
        //show
        repaint();
    }
    void drawPoint(int x,int y,Color c){
        canvas.setRGB(x,y, c.getRGB());
    }
}
```

My User interface

```java
import DrawCanvas.DrawCanvas;
import TextDemo.TextDemo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GUI extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        int width = 1280; int height = 720;

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        panel2.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        //Add contents to the window.
        //frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.add(new TextDemo(),BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(new DrawCanvas(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This is where the user can ener a text

```java
package TextDemo;

import DrawCanvas.DrawCanvas;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField textField;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";
    public static Boolean circle = false;

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);

        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);

        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());

        System.out.println("String is: " + textField.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).replaceAll("\\s+",""));
        String input = textField.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).replaceAll("\\s+","");
        if (input.equals("1")){
            System.out.println("Here");
            DrawCanvas drawCanvas = new DrawCanvas();
            drawCanvas.drawCircle(330,310,50);
        }

        textField.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a DrawCanvas component, but you never add the component to the frame. You need to add the component to a panel of the frame and then invoke revalidate() and repaint().

Comment: @camickr I've added `frame.add(new TextDemo(),BorderLayout.WEST);` in another class and inside the `actionPerformed` i call `drawCanvas.drawCircle(330,310,50);` but that doesn't work
I will just update the code

Comment: You have two instance of DrawCanvas. The instance you create in the ActionListener is not added to the frame. You should only have a single instance of the component then you can invoke any method from that instance.

Comment: Im not really sure how to do this, sorry. Could you maybe show me in an example? or maybe try it here: `wetransfer.com/downloads/f5d4281c5ec108bd9edb815ad27a217820210304212025/f96ce2` which is my project

Comment: See: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).